# Putting random numbers in but still have the triangle work

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{isonums} %for comma in number instead of point
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc,angles,backgrounds}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\sideLabel}[3]{\node at ($($#1!0.5!#2$)!3mm!90:#2$) {$#3$};}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\sideMark}[3]{\node[red] at ($($#1!0.5!#2$)!3mm!90:#2$) {$#3$};}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\angleMark}[4]{
\coordinate (A) at #1;
\coordinate (B) at #2;
\coordinate (C) at #3;
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path pic[red,pic text=$#4$,draw,angle eccentricity=1.6]{angle=C--B--A};
\end{scope}
 }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\angleLabel}[4]{
\coordinate (A) at #1;
\coordinate (B) at #2;
\coordinate (C) at #3;
\path pic[pic text=$#4^\circ$,draw,angle eccentricity=1.6]{angle=C--B--A};
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\solutions}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision={2}}
\node[anchor=north west,red] at (current bounding box.south west){[#1]};}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\SSS}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\angleA = acos((#2^2 + #3^2 -(#1^2))/(2*#2*#3));
\angleB = acos((#1^2 + #3^2 -(#2^2))/(2*#1*#3));
\angleC = 180 - \angleA - \angleB;
}
% draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (\angleB:#3) -- (#1,0) -- cycle;
% labels
\sideLabel{(0,0)}{(\angleB:#3)}{#3}
\sideLabel{(\angleB:#3)}{(#1,0)}{#2}
\sideLabel{(#1,0)}{(0,0)}{#1}
%unknows
\angleMark{(#1,0)}{(\angleB:#3)}{(0,0)}{A}
\angleMark{(\angleB:#3)}{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{B}
\angleMark{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{(\angleB:#3)}{C}
% Solutions
\solutions{$A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\angleA}^\circ$, $B=\pgfmathprintnumber{\angleB}^\circ$, 
$C=\pgfmathprintnumber{\angleC}^\circ$};
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\SAS}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\ThirdSide = sqrt(#1^2 + #3^2 - 2*#1*#3*cos(#2));
\AngleOppositeFirstSide = acos((#3^2 + \ThirdSide^2 -(#1^2))/(2*#3*\ThirdSide));
\AngleOppositeSecondSide = acos((#1^2 + \ThirdSide^2 -(#3^2))/(2*#1*\ThirdSide));
}
%draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide) -- (#1,0) -- cycle;
%labels
\sideLabel{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(#1,0)}{#3}
\sideLabel{(#1,0)}{(0,0)}{#1}
\angleLabel{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{#2}
% unknows
\sideMark{(0,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{a}
\angleMark{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{A}
\angleMark{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{B}
% solutions
\solutions{$a=\pgfmathprintnumber{\ThirdSide}$, 
$A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeFirstSide}^\circ$, 
$B=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeSecondSide}^\circ$}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\ASA}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\ThirdAngle = 180 - #1 - #3;
\SideOppositeFirstAngle =   #2*sin(#1)/sin(\ThirdAngle);
\SideOppositeSecondAngle =  #2*sin(#3)/sin(\ThirdAngle);
}
% draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle) -- (#2,0) -- cycle;
% labels
\angleLabel{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{(0,0)}{(#2,0)}{#1}
\sideLabel{(#2,0)}{(0,0)}{#2}
\angleLabel{(0,0)}{(#2,0)}{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{#3}
% unknows
\sideMark{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{(#2,0)}{a}
\sideMark{(0,0)}{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{b}
\angleMark{(#2,0)}{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{(0,0)}{A}
% solutions
\solutions{$a=\pgfmathprintnumber{\SideOppositeFirstAngle}$, 
$b=\pgfmathprintnumber{\SideOppositeSecondAngle}$, $A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\ThirdAngle}^\circ$}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\AAS}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\ThirdAngle = 180 - #1 - #2;
\SideOppositeSecondAngle =  #3*sin(#2)/sin(#1);
\SideOppositeThirdAngle =   #3*sin(\ThirdAngle)/sin(#1);
}
% draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle) -- (\SideOppositeThirdAngle,0) -- cycle;
% labels
\angleLabel{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{(0,0)}{(\SideOppositeThirdAngle,0)}{#1}
\angleLabel{(0,0)}{(\SideOppositeThirdAngle,0)}{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{#2}
\sideLabel{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{(\SideOppositeThirdAngle,0)}{#3}
%unknows
\sideMark{(\SideOppositeThirdAngle,0)}{(0,0)}{a}
\sideMark{(0,0)}{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{b}
\angleMark{(\SideOppositeThirdAngle,0)}{(#1:\SideOppositeSecondAngle)}{(0,0)}{A}
%solutions
\solutions{$a=\pgfmathprintnumber{\SideOppositeThirdAngle}$, 
$b=\pgfmathprintnumber{\SideOppositeSecondAngle}$, $A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\ThirdAngle}^\circ$}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\SsA}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\AngleOppositeSecondSide = asin((#2/#1)*sin(#3));
\AngleOppositeThirdSide = 180 - #3 -\AngleOppositeSecondSide;
\ThirdSide = #1*sin(\AngleOppositeThirdSide)/sin(#3);
}
%draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide) -- (#1,0) -- cycle;
%labels
\sideLabel{(#1,0)}{(0,0)}{#1}
\sideLabel{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(#1,0)}{#2}
\angleLabel{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{#3}
%unknows
\sideMark{(0,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{a}
\angleMark{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{A}
\angleMark{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{B}
%solutions
\solutions{$a=\pgfmathprintnumber{\ThirdSide}$, 
$A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeSecondSide}^\circ$, 
$B=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeThirdSide}^\circ$}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%First Solution
\newcommand{\sSAfirst}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\AngleOppositeSecondSide = asin((#2/#1)*sin(#3));
\AngleOppositeThirdSide = 180 - #3 -\AngleOppositeSecondSide;
\ThirdSide = #1*sin(\AngleOppositeThirdSide)/sin(#3);
}
% draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide) -- (#1,0) -- cycle;
% labels
\sideLabel{(#1,0)}{(0,0)}{#1}
\sideLabel{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(#1,0)}{#2}
\angleLabel{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{#3}
% unknows
\sideMark{(0,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{a}
\angleMark{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{A}
\angleMark{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{B}
% solutions
\solutions{$a=\pgfmathprintnumber{\ThirdSide}$, 
$A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeSecondSide}^\circ$, 
$B=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeThirdSide}^\circ$}
}
%%%Second Solution
\newcommand{\sSAsecond}[3]{%
\tikzmath{%
\AngleOppositeSecondSide = 180 - asin((#2/#1)*sin(#3));
\AngleOppositeThirdSide = 180 - #3 -\AngleOppositeSecondSide;
\ThirdSide = #1*sin(\AngleOppositeThirdSide)/sin(#3);
}
% draw triangle
\draw (0,0) -- (\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide) -- (#1,0) -- cycle;
% labels
\sideLabel{(#1,0)}{(0,0)}{#1}
\sideLabel{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(#1,0)}{#2}
\angleLabel{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{#3}
% unknows
\sideMark{(0,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{a}
\angleMark{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{A}
\angleMark{(0,0)}{(#1,0)}{(\AngleOppositeSecondSide:\ThirdSide)}{B}
% solutions
\solutions{$a=\pgfmathprintnumber{\ThirdSide}$, 
$A=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeSecondSide}^\circ$, 
$B=\pgfmathprintnumber{\AngleOppositeThirdSide}^\circ$}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\section{SSS} %the sum of any two sides must less then the third side.
\tikz{\SSS{3}{4}{5}}

\section{SAS} %the angle must be less than 180
\tikz{\SAS{5}{40}{4}}

\section{ASA} %the sum of two angle must be less then 180 
\tikz{\ASA{30}{5}{40}}

\section{AAS} %the sum of two angle must be less then 180 
\tikz{\AAS{30}{40}{5}}

\section{SsA} %S must be greater or equal to s. If S is equal to s (isoscele triangle) the 
angle must be less then 90
\tikz{\SsA{5}{4}{40}}

\section{sSA} %S must be greater or equal to s. In this case it's possible to draw two 
different triangles. 
%If S is equal to s (isoscele triangle) the triangle is unique and the same as SsA.
%The angle A must be less then arcsin(s/S)
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\tikz{\sSAfirst{4}{5}{40}}&
\tikz{\sSAsecond{4}{5}{40}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am sorry for the amount of code! But I was wondering if there was a way to create random numbers that actually work for the triangles, for a worksheet. I can create the worksheet and random numbers but sometimes they do now work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain a bit what this is about. You didn't say what this was for, why you wanted random numbers, and what "actually work" means. With the length of this LaTeX code, you can't expect people to guess everything.

Comment: The code works when I type the numbers in manually but I was just wondering if there was a way to generate random numbers that still hold true for the the geometry.

Comment: Why are your code showing several trinangles? -why is one not enough? What does it mean that "numbers that actually work for the triangles"? Are we talking about side lengths and angles? Any side lengths where the sum of two are less the the third will work. Any angles that sum to 180 deg will work.